# Efficiently counting rooms from a floorplan (version 2)

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++14

This is version 2 of [Efficiently counting rooms from a floorplan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200051/efficiently-counting-rooms-from-a-floorplan).  I had accidentally pasted in the wrong version of the code.

### Update

Final version (version 3) of the code with updated test harness is here: [Multithreaded testing for counting rooms from a floor plan solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200145/multithreaded-testing-for-counting-rooms-from-a-floor-plan-solution)

---

I was inspired by [Calculating the number of rooms in a 2D house](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200005/calculating-the-number-of-rooms-in-a-2d-house) and decided to see if I could come up with efficient code to solve the same problem.

To recap, the problem ([from here](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1192/)) is this:

> You are given a map of a building, and your task is to count the number of rooms. The size of the map is \$n \times m\$ squares, and each square is either floor or wall. You can walk left, right, up, and down through the floor squares.
>
> ### Input
>
> The first input line has two integers \$n\$ and \$m\$: the height and width of the map.
>
> Then there are \$n\$ lines of \$m\$ characters that describe the map. Each character is `.` (floor) or `#` (wall).
>
> ### Output
>
> Print one integer: the number of rooms.
>
> ### Constraints
>
> \$1\le n,m \le 2500\$
>
> ### Example
>
> #### Input:
>
> ```
> 5 8
> ########
> #..#...#
> ####.#.#
> #..#...#
> ########
> ```
>
> #### Output:
>
> 3

### Strategy

It seemed to me to be possible to solve the problem by processing line at a time, so that's what my code does.  Specifically, it keeps a tracking `std::vector<std::size_t>` named `tracker` that corresponds to the rooms from the previous row and starts with all zeros.

As it reads each line of input, it processes the line character at a time.  If it's non-empty (that is, if it's a wall), set the corresponding `tracker` entry to 0.

Otherwise, if the previous row (that is, the matching value from the `tracker` vector) was a room, then this is part of the same room.

If the previous character in the same row was a room, this is the same room.

The code also has provisions for recognizing that what it "thought" was two rooms turns out to be one room, and adjusts both the `tracker` vector and the overall `roomcount`.

Because I wanted to be able to test it with many different inputs, my version of the code keeps reading and processing each floor plan until it gets to the end of the file.

The code is time efficient because it makes only a single pass through the input, and it's memory efficient because it only allocates a single \$1 \times m\$ vector.

### Questions

1. **Correctness** - The code works correctly on every input I've tried, but if there is any error in either the code or the algorithm, I'd like to know.
2. **Efficiency** - Could the code be made even more efficient?
3. **Reusability** - This works for a 2D map, but I'd like to adapt it to 3 or more dimensions.  Are there things I could do in this code to make such adaptation simpler?

Any hints on style or any other aspect of the code would be welcome as well.

### rooms.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::size_t rooms(std::istream &in) {
    std::size_t height;
    std::size_t width;
    std::size_t roomcount{0};
    static constexpr char empty{'.'};
    in >> height >> width;
    if (!in)
        return roomcount;
    std::vector<std::size_t> tracker(width, 0);
    for (auto i{height}; i; --i) {
        std::string row;
        in >> row;
        if (row.size() != width) {
            in.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            return roomcount;
        } 
        for (std::size_t j{0}; j < width; ++j) {
            if (row[j] == empty) {
                // continuation from line above?
                if (tracker[j]) {
                    // also from left?
                    if (j && tracker[j-1]) {
                        if (tracker[j-1] < tracker[j]) {
                            tracker[j] = tracker[j-1];
                            --roomcount;
                        } else if (tracker[j] < tracker[j-1]) {
                            // set all contiguous areas to the left
                            for (auto k{j-1}; k; --k) {
                                if (tracker[k]) {
                                    tracker[k] = tracker[j];
                                } else {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            --roomcount;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // continuation from left?
                    if (j && tracker[j-1]) {
                        tracker[j] = tracker[j-1];
                    } else {
                        tracker[j] = ++roomcount;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                tracker[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return roomcount;
}


int main() {
    auto r = rooms(std::cin);
    while (std::cin) {
        std::cout << r << '\n';
        r = rooms(std::cin);
    }
}
```

### test.in

```
5 8
########
#..#...#
####.#.#
#..#...#
########
9 25
#########################
#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#
#########################
#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#
#########################
#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#
#########################
#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#...#
#########################
3 3
...
...
...
3 3
###
...
###
3 3
###
###
###
7 9
#########
#.#.#.#.#
#.#.#.#.#
#.#...#.#
#.#####.#
#.......#
#########
5 8
########
#..#.#.#
##.#.#.#
#..#...#
########
7 8
########
#..#.#.#
##.#.#.#
#..#...#
########
#..#...#
########
7 9
#########
#.#.#.#.#
#.#.#.#.#
#.#.#.#.#
#.#.#.#.#
#.......#
#########
7 9
#########
#.#.##..#
#.#.##.##
#.#.##..#
#.#...#.#
#...#...#
#########
7 9
#########
#.#.....#
#.#.###.#
#.#...#.#
#.#####.#
#.......#
#########
7 9
#########
#.......#
#.#####.#
#.#.#.#.#
#.#.#.#.#
#.......#
#########
```

### Results

Running the program as `rooms <test.in` produces this expected result:

```
3
47
1
1
0
2
2
4
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: What constitutes a room? Maybe I’m just not seeing the bit that defines when a hallway suddenly meets room criteria. Also, I haven’t had a chance to fully analyze your source, but one stand-out for me to answer the “extend to 3D” question is to rename the `height` to `length`.

Comment: It might be easier to use a modified path-finding algorithm, and then instead of setting a goal, mark all blocks (the periods) that were touched as it "tries" to find the goal until it gives up. When it gives up, store the flagged blocks as a segment, then repeat for all remaining non-flagged blocks individually. The # mark would represent a wall, for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called connected component analysis or labeling in the image processing literature. There are many algorithms that try to make this more efficient. You’re only counting regions, not assigning a unique label (i.e. room number) to each region, so you can get away with a somewhat simpler algorithm than I’m used to seeing.

You’ve already got comments on your coding style, I won’t go there again. But you also asked about a 3D extension, and I can give suggestions for that.

A straight-forward extension of your code to 3D would require to store the previous plane (2D data for the previous z coordinate) as well as the previous line. This gets complicated quickly, and will make it impossible to generate an algorithm that works with an arbitrary number of dimensions.

If you are indeed after an algorithm that would work with any number of dimensions, I’d suggest storing the whole floor plan and using a standard labeling algorithm. They’re only a little bit more complicated that what you’re doing, but assign a label to each room element. You’d have a Union-Find data structure to keep track of labels. For each new element you look at all connected elements (the neighbors in the grid) that have already been processed (this is a fixed list of offsets). If any of them has a label, assign the same label to this element. If another one also has a label, set the equivalence between the two labels in your Union-Find data structure.

The very efficient implementations optimize the order in which neighbors are examined, noting that certain neighbors need not be examined at all under certain configurations.

To learn more about these algorithms, look at [YACCLAB](https://github.com/prittt/YACCLAB). It is explicitly 2D, but you can see all the different approaches people have taken here. I wrote a dimensionality-independent version, you can see the code [here](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/src/regions/label.cpp).

Comment: Yes! Using a proven algorithm instead of trying to hack it together in an ad-hoc way leads to success.

Comment: Sure, but that presumes one *knows* the proven algorithm. I didn’t, but now I do.

Comment: @Edward ...which is why I wrote the above. :)

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, it does not work correctly. The output is `0` (zero rooms)
for the floor plan

```
4 6
######
#.#..#
#....#
######
```

After parsing the second row, the room count is two and the tracker
vector is

```
010220
```

Then, when parsing the third row

```
#....#
```

the room count is decremented *twice* from two to zero.

Another example: For

```
7 22
######################
##..##..####..#......#
###....#...##...#....#
#........#.#....#....#
#...#......#..#...####
###.#..#.....#....#.##
######################
```

your program computes 18446744073709551615 rooms (and 3 rooms with the modification from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200070/35991). The correct result is 2 rooms.

Comment: Would forcing the output to 1 in case of apparant 0 fix it? I mean, what does it mean to have 0 rooms anyway? Even if there's only one room and it's not fully enclosed, are there really 0 rooms? Of-course, in this challenge I assume the test cases will always be enclosed. But if the algorithm only fails in 1 specific case and it should always be from 0 to 1, a bandaid may just be all you need.

Comment: @Mast: It is not just one specific case, I just found (and added) another failure case. I have therefore removed by suggested “fix,” it does not help. Actually I am starting to doubt if this approach can be salvaged at all.

Answer (score 7):

I found another problem with the code that isn't quite addressed by [@Martin R](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/35991/martin-r)'s approach.  Here's an example that shows the problem:

```
7 9
#########
#.#.#.#.#
#.#.#...#
#.#...#.#
#.#.#.#.#
#.......#
#########
```

The correct answer is 1 room, but with both the original and the suggested change, I get 18446744073709551615 (equivalent to -1 on my 64-bit machine).  The corrected version of the first `if` clause is this:

```
if (tracker[j]) {
    // also from left?
    if (j && tracker[j-1] && (tracker[j-1] != tracker[j])) {
        auto bigger = tracker[j-1];
        auto smaller = tracker[j];
        // make sure they're in the right order
        if (bigger < smaller) {
            std::swap(smaller, bigger);
        }
        // rooms have joined
        std::replace(tracker.begin(), tracker.end(), bigger, smaller);
        --roomcount;
    }
} else {
```

### Update

Because the code above still failed for some inputs, I changed the algorithm slightly to separately track rooms and merges.  Using that, a new variable `std::size_t merges{0};` is added to the top of the routine and instead of `--roomcount;` above, the line is now `++merges;`.  The final change is to change the line from `return roomcount;` to `return roomcount-merges;`

I am now writing an automated tester to verify this.

### Update 2

The automated tester, reworked (and apparently bug free) version of this code and an independently derived flood-fill version are now all written, tested and posted here: [Multithreaded testing for counting rooms from a floor plan solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200145/multithreaded-testing-for-counting-rooms-from-a-floor-plan-solution)

Comment: You are right, my proposed change does not work correctly, I have therefore removed it from my answer. Unfortunately, this does not work either, see the additional failure case in my answer.

Comment: Alas, you’re right.

Comment: I've updated this answer to (maybe?) fix the code yet again.  Maybe this time it will really work! :)

Answer (score 6):

> Any hints on style or any other aspect of the code would be welcome as well.

Since you explicitly ask for style advice:

> ```
>   std::istream &in
> ```

`&` belongs with the type in C++ as I'm sure you know so maybe this was just a sort of typo.

> ```
>    if (!in)
>        return roomcount;
> ```

I know it's tempting to omit braces for short statements but you're playing with fire everytime you do it. Try to always include them even in short non-production code.
*(Many people leave them out as they are a nuisance to type. If that's case you could make a macro in your favorite text editor to add braces via a shortcut so you have no more excuses for dropping them)*

> ```
>    std::size_t
> ```

It's good to see that you properly prefix every occurrence of `size_t` unfortunately you did not include `<cstddef>`. It *does* get pulled in by every other header you include but you should not rely on that and always include things you use.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance (C++ is not my first language): What should `std::istream &in` correctly be?

Comment: @MartinR Generally `&` and `*` belong with the type in C++ so it would be `std::istream& in`. I can't find an explicit guideline for it but if you take a look at [this](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#example-163) you can see it in action.

Comment: @MartinR [here is another attempt at explaining it](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/style-and-techniques).

Comment: “you're playing with fire everytime you do it” — unfounded claim: there is no evidence that omitting the braces leads to more errors. Notable anecdotes are just that: anecdotes, not evidence. Omitting the braces makes the code terser and removes syntactic clutter so it’s *at least* plausible that the opposite of your claim is the case.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'd rather not fall victim to *goto fail* style bugs but I'm sure smart scientists such as yourself are not prone to making such silly mistakes anyways so go right ahead.

Comment: @yuri “Goto fail” is that anecdote. There’s simply *no evidence* that braces would avoid this class of errors. In the *particular* case of “goto fail”, the error was most likely caused by a wrongly resolved merge conflict, and using braces would simply not have prevented this bug. The whole point is that this is *regardless* of whether one is prone to making silly mistakes. In other words, besides being an anecdote, “goto fail” doesn’t even show a situation in which braces would definitely have helped.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of style, this should be a class with named functions that do specific jobs. This will make the code much easier to read, maintain, and adapt.

Code like this:

```
            } else {
                // continuation from left?
                if (j && tracker[j-1]) {
                    tracker[j] = tracker[j-1];
                } else {
                    tracker[j] = ++roomcount;
                }
            }
```

... would be far clearer like this:

```
void continue_count_from_left() {
    if (j && tracker[j-1]) {
       tracker[j] = tracker[j-1];
    } else {
       tracker[j] = ++roomcount;
    }
}
            ...
            } else {
                continue_count_from_left(); // or a better name
            }
            ...
```

You can also remove comments this way (which is a sign your code is clearer).

I just split that one section into a function. Putting everything in a class would be far better.